# Significance testing for Jensen–Shannon divergence?

Tags: statistical-significance, distance, kullback-leibler, divergence

The [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) (JSD) measures the (dis)similarity between multiple probability distributions.

How can one determine whether the JSD of (a pair of, or multiple) distributions is significant at some given threshold? In particular, I am interested in setting a threshold beyond which a pair of distributions will be rejected as being too dissimilar.

One idea I have is to compare the computed JSD to the corresponding JSDs of Normal distributions that differ in their location and scale, finding the point beyond which a z-score would be significant at the same threshold. Does this make statistical sense?

Comment: It sounds like you might have *samples* from distributions $p$ and $q$, from which the Jensen-Shannon divergence must be *estimated*. And, you want to use that a statistic for testing the null hypothesis that $p=q$. Is that correct? Or, do you have the actual distributions? In which case, the JSD can simply be computed, and you can define any arbitrary threshold that suits your problem.

Comment: Thanks @user20160. Yes, that is all entirely correct. I have an arbitrarily large number of samples following from two MCMC analyses. Would it then make sense to define my arbitrary thresholds based on the properties of normal distributions?

Comment: Could you use bootstrapping?